# Using joboccara / NamedType with strings and operator+

Tags: c++

Jonathan Boccara's NamedType project lets you create types that wrap primitives to give yourself a little more type safety. If you have a method that takes several string arguments, callers of your methods might get the order wrong. But by using NamedTypestd::string..., you prevent that particular problem.

Consider this code:

```
#include <NamedType/named_type.hpp>

class Foo {
public:
     using OwnerName = fluent::NamedType<std::string, fluent::Callable>;

     void myFunction(const OwnerName &ownerName, ...);
}
```

You can't accidentally get the order of arguments wrong. But in my case, I use the ownerName to construct a URL.

```
void Foo::myFunction(const OwnerName &ownerName, ...) {
    string url = "/blah/" + ownerName + ...;
}
```

This code fails to compile. I can fix it with this.

```
    string url = "/blah/" + ownerName.get() + ...;
```

It's an easy solution, but I do this pattern a lot, and I'd like it to be smarter.

I tried looking at Mr. Boccara's various enhancers, such as BinaryAddable, which looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct BinaryAddable : crtp<T, BinaryAddable>
{
    FLUENT_NODISCARD constexpr T operator+(T const& other) const
    {
        return T(this->underlying().get() + other.get());
    }
    FLUENT_CONSTEXPR17 T& operator+=(T const& other)
    {
        this->underlying().get() += other.get();
        return this->underlying();
    }
};
```

And I created this:

```
template <typename T>
struct StringAddable : fluent::crtp<T, StringAddable>
{
    FLUENT_NODISCARD const T operator+(const std::string &rhs) const
    {
        return T(+this->underlying().get() + rhs);
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::string operator+(const char *pre, const StringAddable<T> &post) {
    return string{pre} + post.underlying().get();
}

template <typename T>
std::string operator+(const std::string & pre, const StringAddable<T> &post) {
    return pre + post.underlying().get();
}
```

None of this helped.

Has anyone solved this? I'd like to be able to use my NamedTypestd::string... types as drop-in replacements for std::string in my method calls. For now, I'm dealing with this in some pretty isolated code, and the problem goes away if I do foo.get() as necessary. But I'd like a more elegant solution.

Anyone?

Comment: Looks to me like the main issue is implicit conversion of `NamedType<...>` to `std::string` cannot be selected due to the first argument in your concatenation being a C string literal. Can't you solve this simply by using the string operator from [std::string_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)? `string url = "/blah/"s + ownerName + ...;`